# Is it possible to list AWS instances asynchronously

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Good day, I do not know if this is possible from what I understand of the AWS API documentation, but I was wondering is it possible to use multi threading to list all my instances asynchronously. By that I mean can I create a thread to list a number of instances while  another thread lists a different set. I have a ridiculously large amount to get through hand waiting for the return from the API call seems for too long. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Do the instances have names or tags that you could use a [Filter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/Filter.html) on?  Otherwise, all of the AWS API's use a "token" to get a new batch of results.  I've never tried to get the token up in front of the iteration and then thread off a new request based on that token.

Comment: the API does not support splitting the list arbitrarily. you could parallel by doing different filtering in each (such as instance types) and/or splitting by region.

Comment: yeah I was worried I would not be able to get the token upfront, but thanks threading on different filters should actually do the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, some SDKs do support async operations. See [AmazonEC2Client.describeInstancesAsync()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2AsyncClient.html#describeInstancesAsync-com.amazonaws.handlers.AsyncHandler-) for example in Java.